# Unknown Encoding with IRremote Arduino ESP8266

Tags: controls, clone, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I want to encode my AC remote control and gave me an unknown encoding.

When I press one time on buttons it gives me the same result for all buttons but when I keep press on the button the `RAW` number is changed!

Here is the runtime information:

```
Timestamp : 000626.759
Encoding  : UNKNOWN
Code      : F3457ED1 (114 bits)
Library   : v2.6.0

Raw Timing[227]:
   +  2966, -  1768,    +   418, -  1126,    +   418, -  1124,    +   418, -   408,
   +   416, -   408,    +   416, -   408,    +   416, -  1126,    +   418, -   408,
   +   414, -   424,    +   414, -  1126,    +   418, -  1126,    +   418, -   408,
   +   414, -  1126,    +   416, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -  1126,
   +   416, -  1142,    +   416, -   408,    +   416, -  1126,    +   416, -  1126,
   +   416, -   410,    +   414, -   408,    +   414, -  1126,    +   416, -   410,
   +   414, -   424,    +   414, -  1128,    +   416, -   408,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   408,    +   414, -   410,
   +   412, -   424,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   408,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   424,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -  1128,
   +   416, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -  1126,    +   416, -   410,
   +   412, -   424,    +   414, -  1126,    +   416, -  1130,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   408,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   424,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   408,    +   414, -   410,
   +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,    +   414, -   410,
   +   414, -   426,    +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   410,    +   414, -   410,
   +   412, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   412, -   426,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   414, -   426,    +   410, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   414, -   424,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   410,
   +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   412,    +   412, -   410,
   +   412, -   426,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   410,
   +   414, -   410,    +   414, -   412,    +   412, -   410,    +   412, -   412,
   +   412, -   426,    +   412, -   410,    +   414, -   410,    +   412, -  1128,
   +   414, -  1128,    +   416, -  1128,    +   416, -  1128,    +   414, -   412,
   +   412, -   428,    +   412
```

Here is my code:

```
// UNKNOWN F3457ED1
uint16_t rawData[227] = {
  2966, 1768,  418, 1126,  418, 1124,  418, 408,  416, 408,  416, 408,  416, 1126,  418, 408,
  414, 424,  414, 1126,  418, 1126,  418, 408,  414, 1126,  416, 410,  414, 410,  414, 1126,
  416, 1142,  416, 408,  416, 1126,  416, 1126,  416, 410,  414, 408,  414, 1126,  416, 410,
  414, 424,  414, 1128,  416, 408,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 408,  414, 410,  412,
  424,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 408,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 424,
  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 1128,  416, 410,  414, 410,  414, 1126,  416, 410,  412, 424,  414,
  1126,  416, 1130,  414, 410,  414, 408,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 410,  414, 424,  414, 410,
  414, 408,  414, 410,  412, 412,  412, 410,  412, 410,  414, 410,  414, 426,  412, 412,  412, 410,
  414, 410,  412, 410,  414, 410,  414, 410,  412, 410,  412, 426,  412, 410,  412, 410,  412, 410,
  414, 410,  414, 410,  412, 410,  412, 410,  414, 426,  410, 410,  414, 410,  412, 410,  412, 412,
  412, 410,  414, 410,  412, 410,  414, 424,  412, 410,  412, 412,  412, 410,  412, 410,  412, 412,
  412, 412,  412, 410,  412, 426,  412, 410,  412, 410,  412, 410,  414, 410,  414, 412,  412, 410,
  412, 412,  412, 426,  412, 410,  414, 410,  412, 1128,  414, 1128,  416, 1128,  416, 1128,  414,
  412,  412, 428,  412
};
```

The Library I am using is `IRremoteESP8266` and `IRrecvDumpv2.ino` example file to get the IR code.

I tried my Samsung remote is working fine but my AC remote doesn't give me the right hex code what is the problem here?

Is it from the IR remote it self and can't be solved by the edit the code?

Comment: Where is your code and what have you tried changing to fix/resolve this error?

Comment: @LogicalBranch I tried IRrecvDumpV2 file from the example!